Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime in OracleDataReader in Oracle.ManagedDataAccess
I have a code:
using (OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(query, connection))
{
    using (OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        using (var parser = new ChoParquetWriter(parquetSourcePath)
            .Configure(c => c.RowGroupSize = 1000)
            .NotifyAfter(1000)
            .OnRowsWritten((o, e) => Console.WriteLine($"Rows: {e.RowsWritten} <--- {DateTime.Now}"))
            .Setup(s => s.BeforeRecordFieldWrite += (o, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Source == DBNull.Value)
                    e.Source = null;

            }))
        {
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                parser.Write(reader);
            }
        }
    }
}

Query is a simple:
string query = $"SELECT x.*, x.ROWID FROM {owner}.{tableName} x";
In query I ask for rows from Oracle Database table, where one column is a TIMESTAMP type. I can see, that parser is writing first 2000 rows without exception. But after starting writing another batch, it throws exception:

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime.
at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types.DateTimeConv.ToDateTime(Byte[] byteRep, Boolean isNotTimeStampTZ, Int32 offset, Int32 length)
at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetDateTime(Int32 i)
at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)
at ChoETL.ChoParquetWriter`1.Write(IDataReader dr)

Exception is being thrown at a line:
parser.Write(reader);
I tried to fix it inside .Setup
.Setup(s => s.BeforeRecordFieldWrite += (o, e) =>
{
    if (e.Source == DBNull.Value)
        e.Source = null;
    else if (e.Source is DateTime dt)
    {
        if (dt < DateTime.MinValue || dt > DateTime.MaxValue)
            e.Source = null; // or set to a default value
    }
}))

or
.Setup(s => s.BeforeRecordFieldWrite += (o, e) =>
{
    if (e.Source == DBNull.Value)
        e.Source = null;
    else if (e.Source is string str && DateTime.TryParse(str, out DateTime dt))
    {
        if (dt < DateTime.MinValue || dt > DateTime.MaxValue)
            e.Source = null; // or set to a default value
        else
            e.Source = dt;
    }
})

But it doesn't help.
Can you help me with this? I suspect the problem is with some bad date (example 30 February), but how to prevent it from throwing exception?
Is there a fix without changing query value?

I'm not too familar with oracle DB. But I'd check your database for the corrupt value and correct it. Usually you use typing to avoid issues that you have. If (for whatever reason) your data is corrupt, correct the data and dont build a workaround for that issue.

That would be smart move, yes. Unfortunately I don't have enough privelege for UPDATE or other than SELECT. I can't control data inside database. That is why I am doing workaround. Normally I would correct data, but in this case, I can't.

I have changed my query and added TO_CHAR for problematic columns.
TO_CHAR(BIRTHDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS BIRTHDATE
Now whole code is working.
